# Silverlight MD5 implementation

Tags: silverlight, encryption, md5

I want to encrypt my passwords by using MD5. I searched on google and tried a few things, but it seems like they don't work with me...

I'm using the using System.Security.Cryptography library. That's what most of the people use apparently. I have this library, but when I want to use:

```
 MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
```

it gives me an error...

Has anybody have some experience with MD5 in Silverlight

Help is welcome! :)

Thanks

Comment: Why MD5? Rfc2898DeriveBytes is designed for password hashing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx

Comment: Im gonna try the rfc thingy, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, MD5 is a hash algorithm, not an encryption algorithm...

If you really need to use the MD5 algorithm, I don't have any solution for you.  However, if you want to use the SHA256 hash alogorithm, which is better than the MD5, then here's a code sample:

```
Public Function Hash(ByVal stringToHash As String) As String

    Dim returnValue As String = ""
    Dim unicodeEncoding As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte
    Dim hashAlgorithm As System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm
    Dim hashBytes() As Byte

    'Get the bytes to hash
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToHash) Then
        bytesToHash = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes("")
    Else
        bytesToHash = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(stringToHash)
    End If

    'Get the hashAlgorithm
    hashAlgorithm = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed

    'Hash the bytes and convert it to string
    hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
    returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)

    Return returnValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/12/06/hash-for-the-holidays-managed-implementation-of-crc32-and-md5-algorithms-updated-new-release-of-computefilehashes-for-silverlight-wpf-and-the-command-line.aspx